# $('#formId')[0] not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, cross-browser

I have a form with id `formId`. In JS, while accessing form with

```
$('#formId')[0]
```

it is working in Firefox and Chrome. But in IE it is not working.

In IE if I use

```
$('#formId')
```

it is working but not in Firefox nor Chrome.

Is there any way so that I can access the form in all browsers?

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: Can we see your code? Maybe put up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Use it to do what? post your code...

Comment: jquery version is 1.9.2.

Comment: id's are unique, the response is an Array of course, but you don't need to select the first element

Comment: post your code here. Is there a chance you use 2 different code ? like in one file it's "formId", and in the other "FormId" ?

Comment: What are you doing with it? `$('#formId')[0]` should give you a DOM node while `$('#formId')` should give you a jQuery object wrapping that DOM node.

Comment: How are you determining that "it is not working". Just having `$('#formId')[0]` or `$('#formId')` in your JS will have no visible effect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tQNM4/6/ - working in firefox                      http://jsfiddle.net/tQNM4/3/ - Form hidden value is coming as undefined

Answer (score 2):

`$('#formId')` will do. You don't need to use `[0]`

Id must be unique.

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

**Update**

As commented by [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)

You do need the `[0]` if you want the DOM node and not the jQuery object

Comment: This has nothing to do with having multiple elements with the same ID. The difference is if a DOM node or a jQuery object is desired.